# java crash on HKDFBytesGenerator androidpay

Tags: java, package, bouncycastle

When I run the script locally

HKDFBytesGenerator hkdfBytesGenerator = new HKDFBytesGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
works great and creates the generator, when I upload WAR file (exported from eclipse IDE) and deploy to my dev server the application simply crashes when I get to that line.

Tried surrounding with try/catch - but its like no error is thrown and the output is the path of the package (the app does not get to the next line)

"org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.HKDFBytesGenerator"

Any ideas how to resolve/whats the issue?
The jars are same in my local and remote env.

Comment: use catch (Throwable t) to make sure to catch all exceptions, it may be a ClassNotFoundError? Do you have the proper libraries bundled in your war?

Comment: Throwable t did show ClassNotFoundError! tnx.  and yes its bundled as war file. it was an issue with a missing jar which was not bundled and i had to add it manually